# NullPointerException when encoding string to ASCII values

Tags: java, encoding, nullpointerexception, ascii, asciiencoding

I'm trying to change an input string into it's ASCII code. The string is of indeterminate length, and I need to operate on each characters code individually.

I had this working the other night, but for some reason it just won't now, and I can't figure out why... I get a null pointer exception at the indicated line...

Here is the entire method.

```
    private void encodeEnableButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)      
    {                                                   
       String encoded = msgToEncrpt.getText();
       int[] text = null;
       for (int i=0; i<encoded.length(); i++)
       {
          text[i] = (int)encoded.charAt(i);//Exception occurs here.
          System.out.println(text); 
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[] text = null;
....
text[i] = ....
```

Your array is null when you try to assign value to its element. You have to create array before this operation, i.e.

```
int[] text = new int[encoded.length()];
```

Comment: Sometimes, I feel really stupid when things like this happen. 
Thanks :P

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to set an element of a null array. Change

```
int[] text = null;
```

to

```
int[] text = new int[encoded.length()];
```

Comment: @MikeSaull And we're within 1 second of each other :D

Comment: Hey, you guys can at least rest assured you're both smarter than I. 
xD

Comment: @TyberiusSeppala Please checkmark the answer that you think answers the question best.

Answer (score 3):

The array `text` is `null`, so you can't access it until you initialize it.

```
int[] text = new int[encoded.length()];
```

Additionally, to print the array's contents properly, you'll need to call [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29).

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
int[] text = null;
```

You are not initializing the array properly. In order to add elements or interact with it at all, you need to initialize the array.

```
int[] text = new int[encoded.length()];
```